# WIX -- Change text in repeater depending on the boolean value in the dataset

Tags: boolean, repeater, velo

I'm creating a dynamic page in Wix which goes pretty well. Only struggling with one thing.  I want a textfield in a repeater that is linked to a boolean in a database to display one text or another depending on the state of the boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Because you mentioned you're on a dynamic page, I assume your repeater is connected to a dataset. This makes things a little more complicated because you have to wait for the dataset to load. If you would use `onItemReady()` to set your field values, the dataset would just overwrite them.

You want to do something like this:

```
$w.onReady(function () {
    $w('#dataset1').onReady( () => {
      $w('#repeater1').forEachItem( ($w, itemData, index) => {
          if(itemData.boolField){
              $w('#boolText').text = "Yes Ma'am!";
          }
          else {
              $w('#boolText').text = "No way Jose!";
          }
      } );
  } );
} );
```

Basically, you wait for the dataset to be ready, then loop through all the items in your repeater using the `forEachItem()` callback, and reset the value of the text field based on the value in the boolean field.

Comment: How did you know about `forEachItem`? I was trying to do something like this using jQuery `.each` and I found this answer (which worked). But I hadn't seen `forEachItem`. Is it a Wix thing, or just something in JS I haven't seen yet?

Comment: Indeed, it is a Wix thing. You can find it in the Corvid API Reference: https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/.